# unexpected instance method function ... found in unbound lookup

Tags: java, functional-programming

Why is an instance needed for field `whyIsAnInstanceRequired` and won't work as in field `errWhyIsAnInstanceRequired`?

The compile error is:

```
Error: java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
            unexpected instance method function(programming.java.FunctionalQuestion.Helper,programming.java.FunctionalQuestion) found in unbound lookup
```

See code:

```
public class FunctionalQuestion {

    class Helper { }

    public void setValue (long value) { }

    ObjLongConsumer<FunctionalQuestion> whyIsAnInstanceNotRequired =
        FunctionalQuestion::setValue;

    public void function(Helper helper, FunctionalQuestion functionalQuestion) { }

    BiConsumer<Helper, FunctionalQuestion> whyIsAnInstanceRequired =
        new FunctionalQuestion()::function;

    /*
    * Error: java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
        unexpected instance method function(programming.java.FunctionalQuestion.Helper,programming.java.FunctionalQuestion) found in unbound lookup
    * */
    BiConsumer<Helper, FunctionalQuestion> errWhyIsAnInstanceRequired =
        FunctionalQuestion::function;

}
```

Comment: Well, `function(…)` is not `static`, hence requires an instance for an invocation, whether you invoke it directly like `someInstance.function(…)` or from a method reference.

Comment: But on field whyIsAnInstanceNotRequired, it’s not in a static context and yet it seems to reference statically(without an instance) FunctionalQuestion::setValue, member function.

Comment: If you want to bind the non-`static` context, i.e. `this`, just use `this::function`. Compare with ordinary method invocations; you can’t use `FunctionalQuestion.function(…)` regardless of the context. But you can use `this.function(…)` in a non-`static` context. Or `otherObject.function(…)` in any context. Omitting the context, like with `function(…)`, is not supported for method references. If you want to have that, you’d need a lambda expression, `(h,q) -> function(h,q)`.

Comment: I think I understand the constraints about the static context. 
            But how does it explain, why this works?:  `java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer<FunctionalQuestion> whyIsAnInstanceNotRequired =
                FunctionalQuestion::setValue;
        public void function(Helper helper, FunctionalQuestion functionalQuestion) {}`
        vs
         `java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer<FunctionalQuestion> whyIsAnInstanceNotRequired =
                this::setValue;

        private void setValue(FunctionalQuestion functionalQuestion, long l) {
  }`

Comment: I'm starting to realize it comes down to method signatures. Somehow `this` may imply the first argument, where `static` doesn't affect the method signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this explains why I was surprised by the original code.

This concept is called:

**Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type.**

Example: `ContainingType::methodName` as explained in:
[methodreferences.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

From that document:

> The following is an example of a reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type:

```java
String[] stringArray 
       = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John","Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference `String::compareToIgnoreCase` would have the formal parameter `list (String a, String b)`, where a and b are arbitrary names used to better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)`.